# How to test switch cases of the main function using mockito?

Tags: java, junit, switch-statement, mockito

I have a main class and the main function in it. There's a switch case implemented directly in the main function something like:

```
public class ABC{


     public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int a;
            switch(a)
            {......
             ....... }
         }
}
```

How do I unit test these switch cases using mockito? What's the syntax for passing parameters to when().thenReturn() construct?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to test. Could you provide more content of `ABC`

Answer (score 0):

Mockito has [very extensive Javadoc on its main class](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html), which goes over common topics like [`when().thenReturn()` syntax](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing).

The most important point your case is that *Mockito is designed for easily writing replacement object instances (mocks) when you don't want to use the real ones*. In your case, you probably don't need Mockito, because the only objects you describe in your question are the container object `ABC` and the final builtins `String` and `String[]` that you can't and wouldn't mock.

If, for instance, you use an object to convert the `args[]` parameter into  an `int a`, and you want to simulate that object because it interacts with an external service (or hasn't been written yet), then Mockito would be a good choice for constructing that mock object instance.